# Finding the determinant of a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, sub-array

I'm working on a program where I have to write a method that will find the determinant of a matrix and I'm having some trouble. This is what I have so far.

```
public Matrix determinant() {
Matrix determinantM = new Matrix(this.rows, this.columns);
for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        determinantM.data[r][c] = this.data[r][c];
    }
}
Matrix x = (determinantM.data[1][1] * determinantM.data[2][2]) - (determinantM.data[2][1] * determinantM.data[1][2]);
Matrix y = (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][2]) - (determinantM.data[2][0] * determinantM.data[1][2]);
Matrix z = (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][1]) - (determinantM.data[2][0] * determinantM.data[1][1]);

Matrix newD = (determinantM.data[0][0] * x) - (determinantM.data[0][1] * y) + (determinantM.data[0][2] * 2);
return newD;
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to call it from main

```
 Matrix z = new Matrix(new double[][]{{1, 2, 3},{0, 4, 5},{1, 0, 6}});
    Matrix v = z.determinant();
    System.out.println("v:\n" + v);
```

I'm not really sure if this is the right way to approach this problem or if I just have some mistakes within my code. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-determinant.html) to calculate the determinant of a 3x3 matrix like:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

The determinant will be:

```
|A| = a(ei − fh) − b(di − fg) + c(dh − eg)
```

Therefore, this part of your code:

```
    Matrix x = (determinantM.data[1][1] * determinantM.data[2][2]) - (determinantM.data[2][1] * determinantM.data[1][2]);
    Matrix y = (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][2]) - (determinantM.data[2][0] * determinantM.data[1][2]);
    Matrix z = (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][1]) - (determinantM.data[2][0] * determinantM.data[1][1]);
```

should actually be:

```
double x=(determinantM.data[0][0] * (determinantM.data[1][1] * determinantM.data[2][2] – determinantM.data[1][2] * determinantM.data[2][1]));
double y=(determinantM.data[0][1] * (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][2] – determinantM.data[1][2] * determinantM.data[2][0]));
double z=(determinantM.data[0][2] * (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][1] – determinantM.data[1][1] * determinantM.data[2][0]));
```

Then the determinate would be `x - y + z`;

So you final method should be something like:

```
public double determinant() {
     double x=(determinantM.data[0][0] * (determinantM.data[1][1] * determinantM.data[2][2] – determinantM.data[1][2] * determinantM.data[2][1]));
     double y=(determinantM.data[0][1] * (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][2] – determinantM.data[1][2] * determinantM.data[2][0]));
     double z=(determinantM.data[0][2] * (determinantM.data[1][0] * determinantM.data[2][1] – determinantM.data[1][1] * determinantM.data[2][0]));

     return x - y + z;
 }
```

Since you are not modifying the original matrix, you do not need to make a copy out of it.

This code naturally, only works for matrix `3x3`.